# NPM error with visual studio code

Tags: angular, npm

If I run Visual Studio it shows these errors:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -4058
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> 'F:\AngularNew\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\AngularNew\package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     F:\AngularNew\npm-debug.log

Comment: Is your packages.json in the right folder?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Myself and the rest of the community would love to help you out but I think we need a little more information. What is it you are trying to do? Could you please provide some example code for this problem?
It looks to me like you are missing the package.json file in the project's folder

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar error with Vue and the problem was that terminal (foolishly, on my part) was is a parent directory instead of the correct one (where `package.json` was correctly located).

All I did in terminal was `cd [insert correct directory name here, overwriting brackets]` and that corrected the problem.

Comment: Yes, it worked very fine. Then npm run serve to start serving

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` in the folder where the `package.json` is located

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run this watcher

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

or
remove all caret sign in package.json

Answer (score 0):

It took me forever to find the issue regarding mine, I had windows defender on windows 11 set to control folder access. As soon as I took it off, boom, the problem was finished